# Error on merging duplicate contacts, wordpress, civi 4.4.14

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

Scenario 1:
1.  Select last name, email rule, all contacts
2.  List of potential dups is displayed
3.  Select first pair
        a) Displays error message at the top of the screen:

: title in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php on line 141

Notice: Undefined variable: userRecordUrl in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php on line 143
        b) select merge and go to next pair:

Notice: Undefined variable: title in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php on line 141

Notice: Undefined variable: userRecordUrl in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php on line 143

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php:141) in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php on line 361

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't seem like it, your problem here is very similar to [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/2560/12).  You should check out the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php); notices shouldn't be displayed in a production environment.

As for squelching those notices to begin with - I would see if the problem exists in CiviCRM 4.6 by trying the [demo server](http://demo.civicrm.org).  If not, I'd say it's fine to just suppress notices using the info in the links above.