# Mail merge export issue

Tags: search, pdf

I've had a good search and not seen anyone asking a similar question - I'm testing out the mail merge function to see if it will work for our next mailing. I'm able to export labels as a PDF from an advanced search without any issues. However, any tests I do trying to export a .pdf, .odt, or .docx mail merged document produces a corrupted file - PDF readers all say the document is "damaged" and .docx and .odt produces a file with an awful lot of nonsense in it!

Anyone faced anything similar and found a solution?

Edit

After a bit of googling and messing around, I managed to get it to export the text I wanted in a HTML format. .docx and .odt documents are corrupted, pdfs won't open. At the top of the HTML and .docx documents there is a message saying "Notice: No file uploaded in Unknown on line 0". If I work it out I'll post here, but I can't find any others with similar problems. I've tried on multiple browsers and machines.

I've also tried to export contact data as a .csv file, again without luck. The file is corrupted with just a huge quantity of unintelligible symbols.

Edit 2!

We are running version 5.5.1

Comment: Could you please edit your question to indicate your CiviCRM version?  Thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks! We're on 5.5.1 and it was very recently installed.

Comment: One more request - could you please include a snippet of the gibberish that appears on .odt/.docx exports? Most importantly, does the gibberish begin with `{literal}`?

Comment: Hi, sure - here's the first line. No reference to {literal} : "Notice: No file uploaded in Unknown on line 0
PKºRAM?,n¤[Content_Types].xmlµ??E?E?Jܲ@5?*Q>5'­_²'}?¦DAC?)".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "Notice" in the comment you posted above, it sounds like the issue is one of headers already being sent.

When you generate a .pdf/.docx/.odt file, the web server sends the exact set of bits and bytes necessary to generate that file.  However, it assumes that *no other data is being sent*.  If, before the document is generated, additional data is sent, you'll get a corrupt document.  It looks like that's what you're experiencing.

Check out the answer here: [Error when printing PDF letter or mailing label from search results list](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/error-when-printing-pdf-letter-or-mailing-label-from-search-results-list/2560#2560).  It gives links that explain how to suppress notices on your live site, which should resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, Great - thanks! I'll try and give this a go.